# Getting "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter." when using StreamWriter, not sure why?

Tags: streamwriter

Im using StreamWriter in a loop and on the first write attempt I am getting the "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter" error but the resource has just been opened so im not sure why this is, here is the code:-

```
 if(File.Exists(filename) == false)
                {
                    using (sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(filename)));
                    {
                        for(int i =0; i < mfeTempLoserList.Count -1; i++)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(mfeTempLoserList[i]); //Error happening here on first loop
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so after a bit of asking around and research, I found the error was the semicolon at the end of the using statement. I removed it and now it works fine. Hope this helps someone. So it should look like this:-

```
if(File.Exists(filename) == false)
                {
                    using (sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(filename))) // NO SEMICOLON HERE
                    {
                        for(int i =0; i < mfeTempLoserList.Count -1; i++)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(mfeTempLoserList[i]); //Error happening here on first loop
                        }
                    }   
                }
```